# Flexlm license option file entry

Tags: licensing

Can we keep License reservations and max lines together in the same option file for the same feature ?

for example 
GROUP ABC xyz1 xyz2 xyz3

RESERVE 20 feature USER xyz
MAX 3 feature GROUP ABC

in the above case we have all 20 license reserved for the user xyz and then we tried to keep limit of 0 to group ABC - in this case what would happen ? how does flexlm works ?

any suggestion or solution is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'RESERVE' option attach the increments/feature to USER , HOST , DISPLAY , INTERNET , PROJECT , GROUP , or HOST_GROUP according with the manual. If you make a `lmutil lmstat -c <port@server> -f <feature>`, you'll see something like below. The `RESERVATION` are seen like some used increments. In any case, a limitation imposed to a group could be inferior to a RESERVATION that consume the increments.

With a previous version of LMGRD, I've tried to use the both directives in the same time with no success.

I don't know how the daemon vendor can modify the LMGRD's behaviour.

```
    Users of a-increment:  (Total of 188 licenses issued;  Total of 160 licenses in use)

  "a-increment" v2015.1231, vendor: daemon-vendor
  floating license

  4 RESERVATIONs for GROUP GROUP-OF-PEOPLE_Group (license-server/27000)

  "a-increment" v2016.0331, vendor: daemon-vendor
  floating license

  28 RESERVATIONs for GROUP GROUP-OF-USER_Group (license-server/27000)
  20 RESERVATIONs for GROUP GROUP-OF-USER_Group (license-server/27000)
    tom peanut peanut (v2015.0312) (license-server/27000 1431), start Fri 11/20 9:53, 8 licenses

  "a-increment" v2015.1231, vendor: daemon-vendor
  floating license

  "a-increment" v2016.0331, vendor: daemon-vendor
  floating license

  88 RESERVATIONs for GROUP OTHER-GROUP_Group (license-server/27000)
  12 RESERVATIONs for GROUP OTHER-GROUP_Group (license-server/27000)
```